# Meteor iron-router not inserting template into the correct layout

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I have set up a route

```
this.route('force', {
 path: '/force',
 template: 'showForce',
 layoutTemplate: 'mainpanel'
});
```

The `showForce` template is very simple

```
<template name="showForce">
  <p>show force</p>
</template>
```

as is the `mainPanel` template

```
 <template name="mainpanel">
   {{ yield }}
 </template>
```

but that template has a parent like this

```
<template name="page_logged_in">
  {{> header}}

  <div id="side-panel">
    {{> sidepanel}}
  </div>

  <div id="main-panel">
    {{> mainpanel}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The route does render the template to the page but not in the `yield` position. It displays as a DOM sibling to the `page_logged_in` template.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Updated gist is here https://gist.github.com/ConnorAtherton/8033276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron Router is a bit tricky to get used to.. You should be using the named yields feature and letting Iron Router put the templates in instead of trying to insert the with {{> templateName}}. I created a demo repo based on your code to show how to achieve the results you desire and it's located here: https://github.com/copleykj/ConnorAtherton

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I'm starting to really understand how it works now. It's so close to working perfectly but how could I hook it up so that my child templates get rendered into mainPanel. I've added a comment on GitHub showing where templates should go. Thanks again @Kelly

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to do your router configuration too

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'mainpanel'
});
```

Your route should also be something like this

```
this.route('showForce', {
    path: '/force',
    layoutTemplate: 'mainpanel'
});
```

The 'template' should be the first param. Without the layoutTemplate configured I think iron router uses the body as the yield which is why you might be seeing the dom displaced.

Comment: Added all of that but the router is still using the body to yield. This is the first meteor problem I haven't been able to solve yet. Any suggestions on what we could try next?

Comment: what does your index.html look like?

Comment: I don't think that layoutTemplate needs to be specified in both, this.route and Router.configure.

Comment: @Curious2learn thats right, I thought it could come from the previous route.

Comment: @ConnorAtherton I think this might be the case because you don't have a {{yield}} when the user is not logged in (which during the initial load) occurs so this may be why you get two yields. One from the initial load without any yields and one from after in your main panel

Comment: @Akshat I've played with the templates some more and it is behaving like that because after the first router renders the second is fine and yields correctly. Any idea how to work around this?